# How to append something to the beginning of Regex matches?

Tags: python, regex, url, regexp-replace

This is the regex code:

```
without_header = re.findall('/sports/[a-z0-9\/\.\-\:]*[0-9\.]+cms', without_header_url)
```

It returns me the output of each URL which doesn't have the https header in front.
For example:

```
/sports/cricket/ipl/top-stories/kxip-vs-csk-shane-watson-faf-du-plessis-infuse-life-into-csks-ipl-campaign-shape-confidence-boosting-win-over-kxip/articleshow/78481088.cms'
/sports/football/epl/top-stories/epl-manchester-united-humiliated-as-mourinhos-spurs-win-6-1-at-old-trafford/articleshow/78481304.cms
```

For this, I want to append "https://example.com" in the beginning. I don't want a for loop, is there any efficient way of doing it using re.sub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex in `re.sub`:

```
(?<!:/)(/sports/[a-z0-9/.:-]*[0-9.]+cms)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gTDj83/1)

**Code:**

```
s = re.sub(r'(?<!:/)(/sports/[a-z0-9/.:-]*[0-9.]+cms)', r'https://\1', s)
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!:/)`: Negative lookbehind to assert that we don't have `:/` at previous position
- `(/sports/[a-z0-9/.:-]*[0-9.]+cms)`: Match your text and capture in group #1

Comment: Thank you for your help. The code is working as expected. :D